# Multi branch Pipeline plugin load multiple jenkinsfile per branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am able to load Jenkinsfile automatically through multi branch pipeline plugin with a limitation of only one jenkinsfile per branch.

I have multiple Jenkinsfiles per branch which I want to load, I have tried with below method by creating master Jenkins file and loading specific files. In below code it merges `1.Jenkinsfile` and `2.Jenkinsfile` as one pipeline.

```
node {
  git url: 'git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxxxxx/pipeline.git', branch: 'B1P1'
      sh "ls -latr"
          load '1.Jenkinsfile'
              load '2.Jenkinsfile'

}
```

Is there a way I can load multiple Jenkins pipeline code separately from one branch?

Answer (score 2):

I did this writing a share library (ref https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) containing the following file (in vars/generateJobsForJenkinsfiles.groovy):

```
/**
 * Creates jenkins pipeline jobs from pipeline script files
 * @param gitRepoName name of github repo, e.g. <organisation>/<repository>
 * @param filepattern ant style pattern for pipeline script files for which we want to create jobs
 * @param jobPath closure of type (relativePathToPipelineScript -> jobPath) where jobPath is a string of formated as '<foldername>/../<jobname>' (i.e. jenkins job path)
 */
def call(String gitRepoName, String filepattern, def jobPath) {
    def pipelineJobs = []
    def base = env.WORKSPACE
    def pipelineFiles = new FileNameFinder().getFileNames(base, filepattern)

    for (pipelineFil in pipelineFiles) {

        def relativeScriptPath = (pipelineFil - base).substring(1)
        def _jobPath = jobPath(relativeScriptPath).split('/')
        def jobfolderpath = _jobPath[0..-2]
        def jobname = _jobPath[-1]

        echo "Create jenkins job ${jobfolderpath.join('/')}:${jobname} for $pipelineFil"

        def dslScript = []
        //create folders
        for (i=0;  i<jobfolderpath.size(); i++)
            dslScript << "folder('${jobfolderpath[0..i].join('/')}')"

        //create job
        dslScript << """
            pipelineJob('${jobfolderpath.join('/')}/${jobname}') {
                definition {
                    cpsScm {
                        scm {
                            git {
                                remote {
                                    github('$gitRepoName', 'https')
                                    credentials('github-credentials')
                                }
                                branch('master')
                            }
                        }
                        scriptPath("$relativeScriptPath")
                    }
                }
                configure { d ->
                    d / definition / lightweight(true)
                }
            }
            """
        pipelineJobs << dslScript.join('\n')
        //println dslScript
    }

    if (!pipelineJobs.empty)
        jobDsl sandbox: true, scriptText: pipelineJobs.join('\n'), removedJobAction: 'DELETE', removedViewAction: 'DELETE'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you want to map old Jenkins' jobs (pre pipeline) operating on single branch of some project to a single multi branch pipeline. The appropriate approach would be to create stages that are input dependent (like a question user if he/she wants to deploy to staging / live).

Alternatively you could just create a new separate Pipeline jenkins job that actually references an your project's SCM and points to your other Jenkinsfile (then one pipeline job per every other jenkinsfile).

Comment: so we have different jobs for different task like plan jenkinsfile for review, apply jenkinsfile for applying, destroy jenkinsfile for destroying whatever we created. So no old job.

All need to be loaded across one branch , stage approach still merges the pipeline when i try to load multiple jenkinsfile through master jenkins file.

I need help for automated approach, instead of configuring each jenkinsfile manually.

Comment: If you need to [share some groovy code between Jenkinsfile there is a plugin for that](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin).